# Insert isn't persisted when executing in execute block with return values

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

I try to insert two values into my database with `execute block` and return inserting the id.

```
execute block returns (id integer)
as begin
  insert into test (name) values ('test1') returning id into :id;
  suspend;
  insert into test (name) values ('test2') returning id into :id;
  suspend;
end;
```

If I don't call `fetch|fetchAll` methods the insert isn't persisted in the database.

I can't call `fetchAll` after query executing for multiple read of result set.
But if I call there, the insert is persist and I can get returned values.

Comment: consider rewriting the text or using a spell checker. It's hard to understand what is being asked.

Comment: What do you not undertand ?

Comment: if you do not want to do rowset fetching then make a separate query `insert into test (name) values ( :name ) returning id` then use `bindParam` to set `:name` parameters to different values and execute twice with every value

Comment: `I can't call fetchAll after query executing` because fetching is exactly WHEN select-like queries are being executed. Do the fetching=executing and save all the IDs returned into some PHP data array variable while you are executing the query. Then further on use that variable if you need to reuse the id values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must fetch all rows produced by the execute block, for those statements to be executed. An `execute block` is an anonymous 'stored' procedure, and a `suspend` statement makes it 'selectable`.

When executed, Firebird does the work up to a `suspend` statement, waits for the row to be fetched by the client and then proceeds with the next statements until it hits another `suspend` statement.

If a row is not fetched by the client and the statement is closed / released, then Firebird will roll back all changes until the previous `suspend` (or the start of stored procedure / `execute block` if there is no previous suspend).

In other words, retrieving the rows is required for the `execute block` to have any lasting effect.

Otherwise, it might be better to execute the inserts individually, and simply not use `execute block`.